# Upload Documents in element browser

Tags: typo3

I am running TYPO3 4.5 and I would like to allow editors to upload documents to fileadmin directly in the element browser.

I'm trying to set

```
options.uploadFieldsInTopOfEB = 1
options.createFoldersInEB =1
```

In user TSCONFIG.

It does work for me as admin user, but not for editors.
I've tried it in user and group tsconfig.

If I look at the TSCONFIG tree in the user manager, the option seems to be set for that editor group.
but still, no upload fields showing up.

What does the trick?
Or where else could I look to debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upload fields in the element browser will only show up after a path is defined resp. chosen to upload the files in.
If you look under Admin Tools/User for `default upload path` you'll see `fileadmin/_temp` for the admin user, but none for your editors, since no `_temp_` subdirectory exists at their mount point(s).
You could generate such a subdirectory manually, but it's not necessary. As soon as your editors open the file tree in the EB and choose one directory within, they should be shown the upload fields for this chosen directory.

Comment: Madness! You are right! I had to create a directory fileadmin/editors/_temp_ though (clicking around in the EB wouldn't work), but creating the dir did the trick. Fantastic. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the upload fields are just not beeing displayed? When you edit the usergroup in the tab "Access List" in the area "Allowed excludefields". Just an idea!

Comment: Is there an excludefield for that? I haven't seen anything that looked like a candidate there ...